# i have some problems about routing in node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, single-page-application

my app is SPA using react

I am trying to build API using express in node.js

so my server code is

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 80;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('connected')
}}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
})

//api
app.get('/user', .....
   res.json(~~~)
app.post('/user', .........
   res.json(~~~~)
```

Because my client is spa ( react ),

There is only one 'sendFile' in the server code.

all the rest is API, which returns JSON.

So I want to use API only about fetch or ajax ways

However, the current situation is that if client directly access the api url,

the browser can see json instead of my spa.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

thank you.

Comment: swap the get to a post, change the url slightly then change the get to a redirect back to the spa

Answer (score 1):

To use SPA-way of routing, you need to separate urls of pages and api urls:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 80;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('connected')
}}

//api
app.get('/api/user', .....
   res.json(~~~)
app.post('/api/user', .........
   res.json(~~~~)

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
})
```

Notice that:

1. `/*` route goes after api, so that all routes that don't match previous paths, render your SPA page
2. You need to use `*` in SPA url pattern, so when you route to `/user` it renders SPA page, and then on client you render `user` page
3. `api` prefix, that will differentiate your api and SPA paths